# How do I improve the speed of this program?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I am using Python and the pandas library and two csv files.

A master file that contains all possible occurrences and a subset file that contains a portion of the master file. The files do contain identical column names but differ in row count. The subtest file has results in it but is missing information in two of the columns.

I am able to update the missing information in the subset file using two for loops:

```
for (indexS, valuesS) in subset.iterrows():
    #print(values.values[27])
    for (indexM, valuesM) in master.iterrows():
        if valuesS.values[3] == valuesM.values[3] and valuesS.values[27] == valuesM.values[27]:
            valuesS.values[4] = valuesM.values[4]
            valuesS.values[5] = valuesM.values[5]
            break
    print(valuesS.values[4])
    print(valuesS.values[5])
print(subset)
```

[two for loops filling in missing informaiton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NYWP.png)

But this takes a long time to run. The master file can have 100,000 plus rows. So for it to loop though and check each row is inefficient.

I have been trying to use pandas functions like concat, merge, join, combine_first, but it is producing some odd results. I believe that these built-in functions have the capability to perform the task I am trying and would greatly increase the speed but I am unsure how to use them correctly.

What I am trying to accomplished can best be described as placing two transparent tables overtop of each other and writing the missing information from the master file to the subset file but then removing the master file and keeping the updated subset file.

Comment: Please post as text not screenshot.

Comment: You cannot. You have posted 0 lines of code, which will take no time to execute. You cannot improve something that takes 0 time to execute, so your (non existent) code is as efficient as it could be.

Comment: the code was posted in the link but I have edited the question to include it in-line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you would be to update the subset data frame using the master data frame:

```
subset = subset.set_index([subset.columns[3], subset.columns[27]])
master = master.set_index([master.columns[3], master.columns[27]])
subset.update(master[[master.columns[4], master.columns[5]]])
subset = subset.reset_index()
```